Use JMeter to test the running time of the Azure Data Factory pipeline
We have an Azure Data Factory pipeline and we need to pay attention to its performance. So we try to test it with JMeter.
We want to trigger the debug button multiple times through the API (with different parameters), and then there will be logs in the output. We need to pay attention to whether the value of Duration each time is within the expected range and generate a report:

Is there any experience or documentation how to implement it?

What is your service level agreement with Azure Data Pipeline?  If it is too slow (subjective) who do you report the defect to and what are their SLA's for a fix?
Test what you can own, manage, or control, not the items that you have no control over.   If you want to measure how long something takes then the differences in response time for log events provide a nice passive way to check these items as the pipeline progresses.
The general rule of thumb is you don't point tactical nuclear software (performance testing tools) at production code that is not owned, managed, or controlled by you, or where you have (in writing) permission to do what you are doing that could impact other tenants of the software.
